# Cosmos "Hello world" Plug generate error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cosmos

I've just installed **Cosmos** and tried to run the test program given by default. That's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace CosmosKernel2
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cosmos booted successfully. Type a line of text to get it echoed back.");
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Text typed: ");
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, it says:

```
Error   8   Plug needed. System.Void  System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(System.Object)
   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.ScanMethod(MethodBase aMethod, Boolean aIsPlug) in c:\Data\Sources\Cosmos\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 663
   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.ScanQueue() in c:\Data\Sources\Cosmos\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 779
   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.Execute(MethodBase aStartMethod) in c:\Data\Sources\Cosmos\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 284
   at Cosmos.Build.MSBuild.IL2CPUTask.Execute() in c:\Data\Sources\Cosmos\source2\Build\Cosmos.Build.MSBuild\IL2CPUTask.cs:line 239 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Cosmos\Cosmos.targets    32  10  CosmosKernel2Boot
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, I have installed all requirements listed here: http://cosmos.codeplex.com/releases/view/123476

Thank you in advance!

Comment: note that a console.readline() always returns a string, therefor making it a var is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Cosmos isn't working well with windows 8/8.1. So the only solution is to either install Windows 7 or run a virtual machine with installed Windows 7 (the latter worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

"plug needed" error means that you have used some method which relies on an internal call or PInvoke, and thus Cosmos cannot compile it.

You probably use a method that has not been plugged yet or maybe missing a reference to that implementation (which makes Cosmos think it is not implemented)

Use the below guides to help you getting started:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220076/Csharp-Open-Source-Managed-Operating-System-Intro

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29523/Cosmos-C-Open-Source-Managed-Operating-System

**Update: Try using something similar to this code:**

```
using System;
using Cosmos.Compiler.Builder;

namespace CosmosBoot1
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Cosmos Builder logic
        // Most users wont touch this. This will call the Cosmos Build tool
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildUI.Run();
        }
        #endregion

        // Main entry point of the kernel
        public static void Init()
        {
            var xBoot = new Cosmos.Sys.Boot();
            xBoot.Execute();
            //There's supposed to be a bit of text here. Change it to Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've installed PInvoke, but the problem is still there. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: See this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8_rCIvzq4I , try using something similar to the code in the video.

Comment: I'm still quite new to C#, but the thing is that I need Cosmos for a project in school. Would installing VS 2008 work? I have no preference at all about versions & etc, just a working code that can be booted by a VM. Also, there is no Cosmos.Compiler package installed (it causes an error)

Comment: you can use any visual studio version. just copy paste the code I added in my answer. add Console.WriteLine command with whatever text you would like and it should work for you.

Comment: I did and there are the following errors: The type or namespace name 'Compiler' does not exist in the namespace 'Cosmos' (are you missing an assembly reference?); And the other other one: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile... I downloaded the recommended download from here: http://cosmos.codeplex.com/releases/view/58275

Comment: I think you need to start from the beginning than.... here is a recomended guide for Basic Cosmos and C# : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S2neqs6GLWM1oOl1IbFiLRQMVvIzgsLgsd7_5PnBPFE/edit

Comment: Thanks for all you time! :) But actually this tutorial (which is great and I'm going to use) assumes that I've successfully installed everything needed and that I can run a simple hello world program, but sadly it's not the case-I wrote some code without errors. Here:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace CosmosKernel5
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
            var xBoot = new Cosmos.System.Console();
            xBoot.WriteLine("True");
            while (true) ;
        }
    }
}

Comment: But when I run it, a window pops up saying Assertion failed and that my file.cpdb is missing. How could I fix it? Also in order to compile without any errors, I set it to 32-bit (x86). Thank you!

Comment: It means the pdb linked to cpdb is missing. try to change CPU architecture to any CPU or x64.

Comment: When I try to compile under x64 it says that the namespace Cosmos is missing.